# Why doesn't Dissolve with stats plugin work in QGIS 2.14?

Tags: qgis, statistics, dissolve

In ArgGIS 9.3 there is a function of ArcToolBox named Summary Statistics (Analysis).

I'm finding a similar function on QGis.
One of these is Dissolve with stats (plug in) but on my version of QGIS (2.14.1 Essen) don't work... "*local variable 'nElement' referenced before assignment See log for more details*"

Message Log error: **Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Giuseppe Cillis/.qgis2/python/plugins\DissolveWithStats\dissolve_stats.py", line 71, in run
                self.dlg = dissolve_stats_dialog.DissolveWithStatsDialog(self.iface)
              File "C:/Users/Giuseppe Cillis/.qgis2/python/plugins\DissolveWithStats\dissolve_stats_dialog.py", line 98, in __init__
                listRes = self.calculateFields(listKeep, listStats, output)
              File "C:/Users/Giuseppe Cillis/.qgis2/python/plugins\DissolveWithStats\dissolve_stats_dialog.py", line 274, in calculateFields
                listAttrs[uniqueValuesDissolveField.index(x)].append(y)
            ValueError: u'LAVELLO' is not in list**

Instead, I tried it on an old version (QGIS 2.8 Wien) and it works.

Can i resolve this problem?
Is there an alternative to Dissolve with stats?

Answer (score 1):

You could to use the pluguin "Group stats".

This plugin works like a dynamic table in Excel!

Tutorial:
https://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks carlos!!! This is a good alternative which i will use! But, i would to know because there is this problem with dissolve with stats (and other plug in how dissolve of geoprocessing)! Damned Qgis hahauhahaahau !!!